# What does it mean for something to be "so-called"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, expressions, tone

What does it mean if someone says,

This is the so-called [noun]

or

This is the so-called "[noun]"

What is the purpose of the addition of so-called? Are these sentences neutral or has slightly negative connotation?

*Why the downvotes?*

Comment: If someone says it, it depends on their intonation.

Comment: _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2011) lists these two very different meanings "**1.** Commonly called: _the artificial elevation that often occurs when a doctor or nurse reads a patient's blood pressure—the so-called white-coat syndrome_. **2.** Incorrectly or falsely termed: _My so-called friends were gossiping about me again_. Correctly figuring out the intended meaning in a given instance is chiefly a matter of considering context and word choice ("so-called friends" rarely occurs in sense (1), for example).

Comment: @SvenYargs They're both inadequate though in terms of not covering widely-used meanings. The usage of *so-called* can very often indicate that the speaker does not commit themselves to that description, not that they commit to it being incorrect or falsely termed. It may be a description that is not yet established as accurate, for example. Or one that is controversial, but which the speaker does not wish to take sides on.

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more: Your point is valid and useful. The fuzziness of actual word usage vis-a-vis dictionary definitions applies to many words—although perhaps not often as glaringly as in this case, where a whole category of meanings goes unremarked by AHDEL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes in technical writing, I have met *so-called* used in a neutral way, to say "by the way, this is the word used for the thing I am referring to".

But in normal usage, it is somewhat derogatory, and implies that though somebody uses this word, it is not appropriate, and the people who use it are in some way mistaken, ignorant, or unfashionable.

Comment: It has the same effect as scare quotes, like _He's a "conservative"_, which means the same as _He's a so-called conservative_. It means the speaker takes no responsibility for the correct use of the term; the term originated elsewhere and does not mean what they would ordinarily mean by it.